# extjs setvalue of displayfield overwriting store?

Tags: extjs, data-binding, grid

working on my first extjs project where I have a displayfield, which I populate like so.

```
        var displayfield = this.view.down('#displayfieldAccountPL');
        var selectedAccountRecord = accountSummaryDataStore.findRecord('AcctNum', selectedAccountNumber);
        var acctPL = selectedAccountRecord.get('CalcPLSett');
        displayfield.setValue(acctPL);
```

here is my setup for displayfield

```
                                        xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Account P&L',
                                    //id: 'displayfieldAccountPL',
                                    itemId: 'displayfieldAccountPL',
                                    renderer: function (value) {
                                        var newVal = Ext.util.Format.currency(value, '$ ', 0);
                                        if (value > 0) {
                                            newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + newVal + '</span>';
                                        } else if (value < 0) {
                                            newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + newVal + '</span>';
                                        } else {
                                            newVal = newVal;
                                        }
                                        return newVal;
                                    }
```

Upon selected a button in my project I want to clear out the displayfield.
The problem is, when I set the value to BLANK, I think it is overwriting the store.  I think this because I have the store linked to a grid, and the grid row columns are blanked out after I hit the button.
I think what is occurring is two way binding but all I am trying to do is blank out the displayfield.

```
var displayfieldPL = this.view.down('#displayfieldAccountPL');
displayfieldPL.setValue('');
```

any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Is there an easy way to remove text from a displayfield?

Comment: From the code you showed, this shouldn't happen. Could you make a small Sencha fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: let me try and figure out fiddle.  Haven't been successful yet